# How can I play Flash videos from YouTube louder?

Tags: video, flash, youtube

Some videos played in Firefox just have a too little volume. I have already used alsamixer to turn up the volume to the maximum, and of course I've also turned up the volume of the Flash player to the max. Some videos are still too low.

Comment: what is your OS? Can you post a link to a sample video?

Comment: I would suggest purchasing some external speakers. My computer speakers at maximum were barely audible. The external speakers at half volume are fine.

Comment: Here is one I found too low: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PeuKP5UqTs4 I watch these videos on a Dell Inspiron 1525 laptop with Xubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem with my favorite song. here is a list of solutions I know:

1. Put on a set of headphones if you have any, and mess with the volume on both systems. (You can only do it with the Computer sometimes because only some headphones have the ability to get volume turned up and/or down.)
2. If you have any speakers, connect them to your computer and mess with the volume on both systems.
3. Find another way to watch the video without youtube. if there's any free downloads, you can get the song directly to your computer and hear it from there, it usually has louder sounds in when I do that.

Hope this helped!
( Sorry for bad english, I am from Denmark )